# iOS) How to make Tab View with fixed view at the top and bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, tabbar

I'm in trouble making tab view as I want.

Here's my plan, At the top and bottom, there is each fixed view.
so there must be in-between view.
At there I want to insert Tab bar and subviewcontrollers.

But by using storyboard and tabbarController,
I have to make same fixed views for every sub viewcontroller, isn't it?

How can make it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import view from the tab bar controller to the in-between view in the View controller.

Give a storyboard id to the tab bar controller. Here I am using "Tab".

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UITabBarController* tab = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Tab"];
tab.view.frame = self.inBetweenView.bounds; // replace with your view's name
[self.inBetweenView addSubview:tab.view];

[self addChildViewController:tab];
[tab didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: my senior for your sincere answer.

Comment: There is one thing I ask for,I want to put 'tab's tab bar just below the top view. So I get the top view's height, and tab.tab.origin.y = top view's height, but i couldn't see the tab bar, so I just set it randomly 400 , and there is tab bar in some? middle of tab view. How can I set the value of y of tab's tab bar? Should I just set it properly as constant?